# Canvas lines showing up lighter and then darker

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I was playing around with canvas today and created a little script that places a button graphic when the user clicks on the screen. However, it has a strange glitch: On the initial click, the lines appear to be dark gray, turning solid black on the following click.

Does anybody know why that may be?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8pg7/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="paint.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="paint.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px">Not supported.</canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var paint = {

    init: function() {  
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        $(document).on('click', function(e) {
            var x = e.clientX,
                y = e.clientY;

            paint.draw_button(ctx, x, y, 2, 15);

        });
    },

    draw_button: function(ctx, x, y, scale, rad) {
        scale = scale * 25.5,
        rad = scale - rad;

        ctx.moveTo(x-rad, y-scale);
        ctx.lineTo(x+rad,y-scale);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x+rad, y-scale, x+scale,y-scale, x+scale, y-rad);
        ctx.lineTo(x+scale,y+rad);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x+scale,y+rad, x+scale, y+scale, x+rad, y+scale);
        ctx.lineTo(x-rad,y+scale);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x-rad, y+scale, x-scale, y+scale, x-scale, y+rad);
        ctx.lineTo(x-scale,y-rad);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x-scale,y-rad, x-scale, y-scale, x-rad, y-scale);

        ctx.stroke();
    },
};

$(function() {
    paint.init();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `beginPath()` method or the lines will accumulate for each time you call `stroke()` on them. `beginPath()` will reset the path object:

```
draw_button: function(ctx, x, y, scale, rad) {
    scale = scale * 25.5,
    rad = scale - rad;

    ctx.beginPath(); /// here

    ctx.moveTo(x-rad, y-scale);
    ctx.lineTo(x+rad,y-scale);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x+rad, y-scale, x+scale,y-scale, x+scale, y-rad);
    ctx.lineTo(x+scale,y+rad);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x+scale,y+rad, x+scale, y+scale, x+rad, y+scale);
    ctx.lineTo(x-rad,y+scale);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x-rad, y+scale, x-scale, y+scale, x-scale, y+rad);
    ctx.lineTo(x-scale,y-rad);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x-scale,y-rad, x-scale, y-scale, x-rad, y-scale);

    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Ah well I feel like a fool haha. Thank you!

Comment: @tomc no problem, we all do simple mistakes from time to time :)